# update attribute via link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, update-attribute

Method should update attribute every time user click link_to. Accumulation belongs_to :user and :question

```
 <%= link_to "+1", controller: "/accumulations", action: "vote_up",id: @question, user_id: current_user, method: "post" %>

def vote_up
 @question = Question.find(params[:id])
 @accumulation = Accumulation.where(user_id: current_user.id, question_id: @question.id )
```

Accumulation's 3rd attribute is point:

```
 @accumulation.point = Accumulation.increment_counter(:point, @accumulation)
 @accumulation.save
 redirect_to :back, notice: "+1"
end
```

It gives me this message:

undefined method `point=' for # ActiveRecord::Relation:0xaa7fc10

How can I update attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is only one accumulation for any given user/question combo, you can add `.first` to your query:

```
@accumulation = Accumulation.where(user_id: current_user.id, question_id: @question.id ).first
```

Otherwise, you're trying to set `point` on a collection of records rather than an individual ActiveRecord object.